# What is $\int_{-1}^{1} x^2 d(\ln x)$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to deal with the following integral: $$\int_{-1}^{1} x^2 d(\ln x)$$

It immediately struck me that why not put $d(\ln x) = \dfrac{dx}{x}$ and simply integrate, so we get answer as zero.

Other way would also be to put $x = e^u$, and integrate, which would give $\dfrac{e^2 - e^{-2}}{2}$.

Which approach is correct? Why and how to decide the procedure in such question?

Comment: How is $\ln x$ defined as $x\to-1$?

Comment: @JasonM taking in account complex plane it will be `i \pi` and with the proper limits it results in zero: $\int_{i\pi}^{2i\pi}e^{2u}du=0$.

Comment: @OlivierOloa We were told that whatever appears inside d (here - $\ln x$), that thing goes from lower limit to upper limit. So we were told that here, $\ln x$ goes from -1 to 1 ! Is it correct?

Comment: @samjoe If this is a *Stieltjes integral*, one may recall that we have $\int_a^b f(x) \, dg(x)$ obtained as the limit of $S(P,f,g) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(c_i)(g(x_{i+1})-g(x_i))$. That's why I asked for more information about $\ln x$ as $x \to -1$.

Comment: @OlivierOloa if it is that, then what I said would be correct or wrong?

Comment: I just think that what you wrote is not a *standard* integral notation.

Comment: In the *usual* notation the limits are meant to be for $x$. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:  I'm adding this to be explicit because a surprisingly large number of people are missing it.
$\int_{-1}^1 x^2 d(\ln x)$ means $\ln x \in [-1, 1]$, and **not** $x \in [-1,1]$.  Note that we have $d(\ln x)$ and **not** $dx$.

Original response:

Since we have $d(\ln x)$ and the limits of integration are $-1$ and $1$, then:
$$ \ln x = -1 \implies x= 1/e$$
and
$$\ln x = 1 \implies x=e$$

Also, $d(\ln x) = dx/x$, so the integral becomes:
$$ \int_{1/e}^e x \ dx$$

Addendum:

Evaluating this integral shows that your second method in the question is correct.  Your first method would've been correct if you changed the limits of integration when you changed from $d(\ln x)$ to $dx/x$.

Comment: @downvoter, care to explain?

Answer (score 1):

$\int_{-1}^1x^2d(\ln{x})=\int_{-1}^1x^2du$ where $u=\ln{x}$

$$u=\ln{x}\implies\frac{du}{dx}=\frac1x\implies du=\frac{dx}x$$
Now substitute $du$ with $\frac{dx}x$. Remember that you have to apply the function $u$ to the lower and upper limits of the integral.
$$\int_{e^{-1}}^{e^1}x^2\frac{dx}x=\int_{e^{-1}}^{e^1}xdx=\frac{x^2}2|_{e^{-1}}^{e}$$
$$=\frac{e^2}2-\frac{e^{-2}}2=\frac{e^2-e^{-2}}2=\sinh2$$

---

I apologize for my error in my first answer. Your second method was correct.

Comment: There's no negative in the final answer

Comment: @WillFisher Sorry about that. I just fixed it.

Comment: @Polygon I think you might have the limits of integration wrong at the end.  From the original integral, since the "variable of integration" is $\ln x$, I believe the OP intends for the limits of $\ln x$ to go from -1 to 1.  Then, to get the limits in terms of $x$, you would invert the $\ln$ function to get $1/e$ and $e$.

Comment: @nukeguy you are right! Changing it right now